# Cardinality of the set difference.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If $B\subset A$, is it true that $Card(A)\backslash Card(B)$ is idempotent to $A\backslash B$ ? It seems to be true though I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: What is your definition of $(\text {Card } A) \backslash \text {Card } B$?

Comment: Besides having a definition of $Card(A)\setminus Card(B)$ you'll also need a definition of what you mean by "xxx is idempotent to yyy". I've only seen the concept of idempotency as in "xxx is idempoptent" or "yyy is idempotent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not necessarily true.  For instance, let $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=\mathbb{N}$.  Then $A\setminus B$ is infinite, but $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality so the set difference between their cardinalities is empty.